# How to handle a W-2 with an old address?

Tags: united-states, taxes, withholding, form-w-2

I telecommute and have a W-2 from a company in MD, with MD taxes withheld (box 15). The address on the W-2 is my old address in IL, but I now live in NM. I plan on filing taxes in NM and MD. Do I need to do anything for IL?

Comment: Did you work anywhere while you were in Illinois?

Comment: Did they withhold any state taxes? If so, which state(s)?

Comment: Wasn't in Illinois - my employer is just painfully slow (like years) to get around to updating addresses and things.

Comment: Withheld MD taxes

Answer (score 2):

If all the taxes were withheld for Maryland, and you lived in New Mexico the whole year, you do not have to file anything in Illinois. You should update your address with your employer.